# Wired connection problem on 18.04 - WiFi works

Tags: 18.04, internet, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 laptop which I mainly use for gaming. So it's a big deal for me if my Internet connection isn't stable. The Wi-Fi signal is weak in my room so I use a LAN cable comming through the wall to use a wired connection.

I have been having an issue with my Ethernet connection. At first, it would randomly disconnect for about 1min then come online again. I'd check if my RJ-45 (default LAN connector) was unplugged, but it never seemed to be the cause. This didn't happen every day. Now this issue has worsened to the point it happens around 30min after every booting, doesn't come online back after, until I reboot the system.

I suspect of my network card or drivers, because every time my Ethernet disconnects in this way, it finds the Wi-Fi network and connects to it, and the Wi-Fi works (though games are unplayable on it because of high ping). The problem could be on the modem/router, technically.

I need your help to diagnose whether the problem is on my modem/router or on my laptop, and if on laptop, whether this is a software problem, hardware, or both; then a way to fix it.

(English isn't my first language, I apologise in advance for any grammar mistakes or lack of clarity.)

Comment: Hey Imamura, i might not be able to find a solution for your problem, but i am pretty sure that anyone who wants to assist you needs some technical details. So please give us the output of `lshw -C Network && lspci -knn | grep -i ether -A 3 && lsb_release -a && uname -a` also the output of `dmesg` might be helpfull. To be more specific `dmesg | grep ethernet-driver OR dmesg | grep ethernet-interface-name` Saludos, Ale

Comment: @AlexOnLinux should be `sudo lshw -C network`. Otherwise, good call.

Comment: Please describe your ethernet network cabling. What is connected to what, and how? Have you tried going directly to the cable/dsl modem?